# LINQ check value NOT IN multiple list of custom Object

Tags: c#, lambda

I am not able to translate following SQL query into lambda expression IN C#. I have tried with join but its giving me error.

SQL Query is:

```
            SELECT DISTINCT Customer.* FROM Customer INNER JOIN RouteCustomer ON Customer.CustomerId = RouteCustomer.CustomerId 
        WHERE
            RouteCustomer.RouteId = @RouteId AND 
            Customer.Inactive = 0 AND
           AND 
            (
                (Customer.CustomerId NOT IN (SELECT CustomerId FROM RouteStopScheduleRule WHERE @Date >= EffectiveDate AND Inactive = 0))
            OR
            (
                (Customer.CustomerId IN (SELECT CustomerId FROM RouteStopScheduleRule WHERE @Date >= EffectiveDate AND Inactive = 0 AND WeeklyFrequency = 0))
                AND
                (Customer.CustomerId NOT IN (SELECT CustomerId FROM RouteStopScheduleRule WHERE @Date >= EffectiveDate AND Inactive = 0 AND WeeklyFrequency != 0))
            )
            )
```

Code I have tried in C# is

```
        IEnumerable<RouteStopScheduleRule> RSRList1 = App.Database.AllRouteStopScheduleRule.Where(rsr1 => rsr1.EffectiveDate >= Date && rsr1.Inactive == false).AsEnumerable();
        IEnumerable<RouteStopScheduleRule> RSRList2 = App.Database.AllRouteStopScheduleRule.Where(rsr2 => rsr2.EffectiveDate >= Date && rsr2.Inactive == false && rsr2.WeeklyFrequency == 0).AsEnumerable();
        IEnumerable<RouteStopScheduleRule> RSRList3 = App.Database.AllRouteStopScheduleRule.Where(rsr3 => rsr3.EffectiveDate >= Date && rsr3.Inactive == false && rsr3.WeeklyFrequency != 0).AsEnumerable();

        List<Customer> _Result = new List<Customer>();
        var _Prelist = App.Database.AllCustomer.Where(c1 => c1.Inactive == false)
             .Join(App.Database.AllRouteCustomer.Where(rc1 => rc1.RouteId == RouteId && (rc1.EffectiveDate <= Date && (rc1.ExpiryDate <= Date || rc1.ExpiryDate.Value.AddYears(1) <= Date))),
                 rc => rc.CustomerId,
                 c => c.CustomerId,
                 (rc, c) => new { CustomerId = c.CustomerId })
                 .Where(x => (!RSRList1.Contains(x.CustomerId)) || (RSRList2.Contains(x.CustomerId) && (!RSRList3.Contains(x.CustomerId))));
```

but its giving me error at all list RSRList1,RSRList2 and RSRList3 as  IEnumerable<> doesnot contains definition for 'Contains'

whats I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

To use Contains in Linq to Sql, the lists needs to be of simple types and not complex objects (In order to the provider to simply convert it to `IN` clause). So you need to changes your lists to be:

```
var RSRList1 = App.Database.AllRouteStopScheduleRule.Where(rsr1 => 
                                 rsr1.EffectiveDate >= Date && rsr1.Inactive == false)
                                                  .AsEnumerable().Select(x=> x.CustomerId);
```

Same goes for the other two lists.

When you need to use Contains for a specific property, let's say and integer then the `List<int>` is the sequence that you need. You do that using `Select` (aka projection).